# User session not updating on node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, session

I am currently working on getting a user's session to update following an update request from the client. The idea here is to display the updated user data immediately to the Client after update is succesful. For this I use sessions to store the data instead of having to make a get-request to the database one every refresh.

My issue is that whenever a user updates himself, the session is still keeping the prior value retrieved after login despite me setting it to a new one. So the updateMyProfile request does not save the data in the session. This is something I test with my Authenticate request that is called on refresh to retrieve user data for a currentUser

/Server

```
  app.use(
  session({
    key: "someID",
    secret: "someSecret",    //Normally this has to be long and complex for security
    resave: false,
    rolling: true,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {  //How long will the cookie live for?
      expires: 60 * 60 * 1000, //Expires after one hour
    }
  }));


 app.patch('/updateMyProfile', verifyJWT, async(req, res) => {
      const name = req.body.name;
      const email = req.body.email;
      const phoneNr = req.body.phoneNr;
      const id = req.body.id;
    
      var updated = "UPDATE users set name = ?, email = ?, phoneNr = ? WHERE id = ?;";
      var retrieved = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?;";
    
      db.query(updated, [name, email, phoneNr, id],  
        (err, result) => {
        if (err)  {
          res.send({message: err}) //Sending error to front-end
          console.log(err);
       }
         if (result) {
         db.query(retrieved, id, 
         (err, resultRetrieved) => {
          if (err) {
          res.send({message: err}) //Sending error to front-end
          console.log(err);
       } else {
           req.session.user = resultRetrieved;   //Session is updated to contain new data!
           res.send({user: resultRetrieved, message: "Update succesful!"});
           console.log("User is now: " + req.session.user[0].name);
           res.end();
       }
      })}
    });
    });
```

//This method is called on every refresh on client via the UseEffect function

```
app.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => { //An endpoint for user-auth

  const token = req.body.token;
  const userSession = req.session.user;

   jwt.verify(token, "jwtSecret", (err, decoded) => {
     
    if (err) {
    res.send({auth: false, user: "No valid token!"});
    console.log('No valid token');
    } 
    else if (userSession) {   //Verified user! < ----------------->
      res.send({auth: true, user: userSession});
      console.log(userSession[0].name + ' is in!');
    }
    else   { //Else if user is not verified, we return an empty object with rejected authentication 
    res.send({auth: false, user: 'No user session!'});
    console.log('No user session');
    }
})
});
```

This is an example from Client on an update request

```
 const update = () => {

    Axios.patch("http://localhost:3001/updateMyProfile", {name: name, email: email, phoneNr: phoneNr, id: id}, 
    {headers: {"x-access-token": localStorage.getItem("token")}}
    ).then(
      (response) => {
        alert(response.data.message);
      }
    );
   }
```

Comment: What are the results showing when you output the new user details with " console.log("User is now: " + req.session.user[0].name);"?

Comment: Why are you setting the session to contain an array of users rather than only the user info you need? I don't think this is related to your problem, I'm just curious.

Comment: Your "updateMyProfile" endpoint is very dangerous from what I can see here.
If I am authenticated as userID 1, I can make a PUT request to /updateMyProfile and pass in the userID 2, and your system will not only update that user with whatever I choose, but also switch my session to that user. This is effectively an account takeover.

You must remember to check that the ID on the JWT is the same as the ID of the account I'm trying to modify. An access control system of some sort needs implementing here

Comment: @Dutchman Thanks for your replies
1) The value from req.session.user[0].name is the user's updated name. So the funny thing is that it actually catches the new data but then does not save it on refresh into the session.
2) Where am I setting the session to contain an array of users? As far as I can see it should only be a specific row as its indexing on 'id' from database.
3) Thanks, I see the problem there, and would definitely have to put a check function into that end-point method
Did you have any clue on the cause of the session not saving the newly added data?

Comment: For clarity, you say "//This method is called on every refresh on client via the UseEffect function". Do you mean the /authenticate endpoint is called on every client refresh, if so, why is that?

Comment: @Dutchman, yes the 'authenticate' endpoint is called on every client refresh, and this is to keep the data in the Client via the Context API. After days and days of figuring out how to persist a user unto the client, I came up with this solution (Obviously based on information and sparring)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how the logic of your authenticate endpoint works.
From what I read, the code verifies the JWT you submit to it, and then returns success if the user already has a session, and false if not. It never actually does anything with the token or generates a session

Comment: @Dutchman, Yes, you are right with your assumption, The point of it is just to check if a user remains logged in. The overall purpose here is just to persist the logged-in user. This end-point is not supposed to do more than that. Now, I think the req.session.user coming over from client has not been updated from the 'updateMyProfile' endpoint. But I am still not sure as I cannot debug it properly :(

Comment: Is there a reason why you need both a JWT and the session? I've not seen a mixture of both like this before. You can use just the JWT to authenticate, or you can use just the session for session management. What's the benefit of both?
You can simply check if the session exists and respond accordingly without any JWT at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242069/discussion-between-dutchman-and-jeff-meindring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

The code above, while a little unusual in the way it mixes uses of server-side sessions and client-side sessions (JWTs), is not incorrect or broken.

The problem in this case was on the client-side, with the way cookies were handled - meaning that updates seemingly weren't being applied to session data.

The session cookie was being set correctly by the server, and accepted by the client, however was not being included in further requests. This meant that the future requests seemed to have incorrect session data because the server saw each request as a brand new request without a previously existing session.
This fact was hidden because the JWT is being used to verify the user is logged in, rather than checking the server-side session.

## The Solution

Axios is being used to make requests on the client-side, the requests were not being sent with the appropriate cookie header.

To remediate this, each request should be provided with the `withCredentials` option like so:

```
Axios.patch(address, data, { withCredentials: true }).then(handleResponse);
```